# sqlAlchemy ORM DDL (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I've prepared test case based on sqlAlchemy documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping

installation versions:

```
cx-Oracle==8.2.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.21
```

DB Version:

```
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

DDL:

```
import urllib

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR2(10))
    fullname = Column(VARCHAR2(10))
    nickname = Column(VARCHAR2(10))

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                            self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
PASSWORD = 'pass'

conn_str = (f"oracle+cx_oracle://AIM:{urllib.parse.quote_plus(PASSWORD)}@host:1521/?service_name=service")

engine = create_engine(conn_str)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

And I get really weird error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE users (
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out exactly what the problem is, but this might help: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/ora-00904-invalid-identifier/ ... I don't think any of your column names are actually reserved words but you might try changing the column names (e.g. `uid`, `user_name`), just in case?

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like Oracle CREATE TABLE behaves a bit differently with respect to primary keys: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-create-table/ ... I don't see examples where people use a column simply called `id`, so this feels like the most likely source of the problem.